# How can I remove weekends in matplotlib for data of variable frequency in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, data-analysis

I looked for an answer to the below, but they're never quite right.

Say we have data of variable frequency in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
testDf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ImpliedVolatility': {
        pd.Timestamp('2022-11-30 16:20:00+0100'): 19.1269013106775,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-11-30 16:30:00+0100'): 19.0800712368193,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-01 15:20:00+0100'): 19.5300982613676,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-02 09:00:00+0100'): 18.8579952967423,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-02 09:20:00+0100'): 18.6791915364582,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-02 15:10:00+0100'): 18.5538057657658,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-02 15:20:00+0100'): 18.6965706501837,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-02 15:50:00+0100'): 17.5678872272944,
        pd.Timestamp('2022-12-05 09:00:00+0100'): 18.2304285690717}})
```

It's simple to get a sensible graph out:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig1.autofmt_xdate()
ax1.plot(testDf.ImpliedVolatility, 'o-')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph with weekend gaps]

However, I would like to get rid of weekend gaps in this graph. To be precise: Fridays at midnight to Sundays at midnight.

Solutions online have several issues, the most common one is that it resets ticker frequencies to regular intervals:

```
import numpy as np
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1)

# write a custom formatter
N = len(testDf)
ind = np.arange(N)  # the evenly spaced plot indices

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    thisind = np.clip(int(x + 0.5), 0, N - 1)
    return testDf.index[thisind].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %Hh')

ax = axes
ax.plot(ind, testDf.ImpliedVolatility, 'o-')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Weekday graph with regular interval gaps]

But that is inadequate here since we have data of variable frequency.

N.B.: the best would be a graph that removes all non-trading-hours, but that's difficult since it is different for each exchange. Here I'm interested in the EUREX Exchange for Options.

I tried several solutions given online - including StackOverflow. Solutions online have several issues, the most common one is that it resets x-ticker frequencies to regular intervals.